# Getting weird indentation error on python tkinter - unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, tkinter, indentation

I'm just adding 1 def with 2 lines of code before it gets indentation error. I'm trying to modify the code that generated from PAGE `Tkinter` GUI editor for login message box. I really don't know why this happens.

I did the exact same code as [this guy on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCAWWUhwEUQ) and I tried to move the def into the far-most left neither right.

So what I'm trying to add is. `def cancelLogin()` inside the login page class. It shows me indentation error on `def init()`. Please help me to figure this out.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 4.20
#  in conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Feb 07, 2019 05:38:55 AM EST  platform: Linux

import sys
import tkMessageBox

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import jta_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = Login_page (root)
    jta_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_Login_page(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Login_page (w)
    jta_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Login_page():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class Login_page:

    def cancelLogin(self):
        msg=tkMessageBox.askyesno("Login page","Are you sure , you want to cancel login?")

    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92' 
        font11 = "-family {DejaVu Sans} -size 10 -weight bold -slant "  \
            "roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0"
        font17 = "-family {DejaVu Sans} -size 13 -weight bold -slant "  \
            "roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0"
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

        top.geometry("584x457+1039+55")
        top.title("JTA Login")
        top.configure(relief="ridge")
        top.configure(background="#201856")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#000000")

        self.btnLogin = tk.Button(top)
        self.btnLogin.place(relx=0.634, rely=0.744, height=54, width=101)
        self.btnLogin.configure(background="#201856")
        self.btnLogin.configure(borderwidth="0")
        self.btnLogin.configure(font=font11)
        self.btnLogin.configure(highlightbackground="#201856")
        self._img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="../../Downloads/button.png")
        self.btnLogin.configure(image=self._img1)
        self.btnLogin.configure(padx="6m")
        self.btnLogin.configure(pady="3m")
        self.btnLogin.configure(text='''Login''')
        self.btnLogin.configure(width=101)

        self.btnExit = tk.Button(top)
        self.btnExit.place(relx=0.223, rely=0.744, height=55, width=97)
        self.btnExit.configure(activebackground="#ffffff")
        self.btnExit.configure(background="#201856")
        self.btnExit.configure(borderwidth="0")
        self.btnExit.configure(font=font11)
        self.btnExit.configure(highlightbackground="#201856")
        self._img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="../../Downloads/button(1).png")
        self.btnExit.configure(image=self._img2)
        self.btnExit.configure(padx="6m")
        self.btnExit.configure(pady="3m")
        self.btnExit.configure(text='''Exit''')
        self.btnExit.configure(width=97)

        self.txtUsername = tk.Entry(top)
        self.txtUsername.place(relx=0.462, rely=0.372, height=40, relwidth=0.342)

        self.txtUsername.configure(background="white")
        self.txtUsername.configure(font="TkFixedFont")

        self.txtPassword = tk.Entry(top)
        self.txtPassword.place(relx=0.462, rely=0.547, height=40, relwidth=0.342)

        self.txtPassword.configure(background="white")
        self.txtPassword.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.txtPassword.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")

        self.Label1 = tk.Label(top)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.205, rely=0.372, height=40, width=100)
        self.Label1.configure(background="#201856")
        self.Label1.configure(font=font17)
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#ffffff")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''Username''')

        self.Label1_3 = tk.Label(top)
        self.Label1_3.place(relx=0.205, rely=0.547, height=40, width=100)
        self.Label1_3.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label1_3.configure(background="#201856")
        self.Label1_3.configure(font=font17)
        self.Label1_3.configure(foreground="#ffffff")
        self.Label1_3.configure(text='''Password''')

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(top,font="TkMenuFont",bg=_bgcolor,fg=_fgcolor)
        top.configure(menu = self.menubar)

        self.TLabel1 = ttk.Label(top)
        self.TLabel1.place(relx=0.154, rely=0.022, height=131, width=423)
        self.TLabel1.configure(background="#201856")
        self.TLabel1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.TLabel1.configure(font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.TLabel1.configure(relief='flat')
        self.TLabel1.configure(text='''Tlabel''')
        self.TLabel1.configure(width=423)
        self._img3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="./jtalogo.png")
        self.TLabel1.configure(image=self._img3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

without the "def cancelLogin()" it works fine as usual

actual result :
  File "./jta.py", line 52
    def **init**(self, top=None):
                                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Are you indenting with space or with tab?
Try to indent with spaces...

Comment: i've tried both. i'm currently using gedit editor which has nice grid lines behind the code so i would've known if something is not indented well

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces. In particular, that problematic `def` seems to be indented with one level spaces and another level tabs, whereas the rest is indentex just with spaces.

Comment: thank you @tobias_k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
grep -C 7 "__init" YOUR_FILE.py | tr ' \t' '.*'
```

This will translate spaces into dots, and tabs into stars. Then you can check if there is a mismatch there.

This is the output when I tried it on the code you posted (from the question source):

```
$ grep -C 7 "__init" test.py | tr ' \t' '.*'
........w.=.None
....
....class.Login_page:
....
....*def.cancelLogin(self):
....**msg=tkMessageBox.askyesno("Login.page","Are.you.sure.,.you.want.to.cancel.login?")
....
........def.__init__(self,.top=None):
............'''This.class.configures.and.populates.the.toplevel.window.
...............top.is.the.toplevel.containing.window.'''
............_bgcolor.=.'#d9d9d9'..#.X11.color:.'gray85'
............_fgcolor.=.'#000000'..#.X11.color:.'black'
............_compcolor.=.'#d9d9d9'.#.X11.color:.'gray85'
............_ana1color.=.'#d9d9d9'.#.X11.color:.'gray85'.
............_ana2color.=.'#ececec'.#.Closest.X11.color:.'gray92'.
```

As stated by @tobias_k, there are tabs and spaces mixed in the lines you added.

Comment: So, what does the output tell us? BTW, did you copy that code from the rendered output or from the question source? Because tabs are automatically translated to spaces in the rendered output.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k, you are right. I updated the answer

Comment: i didn't know tabs and spaces can't get along together. thank you all for your participation.

Comment: That's what most developers don't like about python...
My solution is to always ident with spaces. unless i am using an IDE (like PyDev on Eclipse, or PyCharm) then tabs are automatically translated to a constant number of spaces!